# Using the Kinect for video conferencing

Tags: skype, conferencing, kinect, google-hangouts

Two years ago I bought a Kinect for my XBox 360 in the naive hope that Microsoft would release Skype for the console.

Sadly they didn't but I would still like to use the Kinect for video conferencing on my HDMI television.

Is there a way to achieve this? Ideally using Google Hangouts or Skype.

Do Chromeboxes support the Kinect?

Comment: No; the 360 hardware isn't even compatible with a PC because there isn't a driver

Comment: I thought there was an unofficial driver for the XBox version of the Kinect?

Comment: Yes, you can use an xbox kinect on pc. [Here](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Xs7JICYi5bY) is a related youtube video and [here](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how-tos/how_hack_your_kinect) is a related article. It'll take some technical know-how and a little bit more money, but it is possible to do!

Comment: @Rich - I wouldn't know. I have only ever used the official device with the official drivers on Windows.  I can tell you both versions of the Kintect for the pc ( version 1 and version 2 ) both worth with Skype flawlessly.

Comment: @slow_excellence you should post your links as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox version of the Kinect can be used on the PC with a little bit of work. Upon review of the links, I'd recommend the [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYkddnrcSQ0#t=13) since I didn't have the time to watch the whole youtube video at the time I first posted.

To use it you need the following:

- A [Kinect Power Supply Adapter](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Kinect-Sensor-Power-Supply/productID.253690100)
- The [Kinect SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27876)
- [Kinextcam.ax](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7bwfep71evGcEIwdWRwN0VUQksxTzBOWTloSFZiZw/edit?pli=1)

At this point, just follow the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYkddnrcSQ0#t=13) in order to install the proper drivers and get everything set up. I've wanted to do this for a while, but haven't since I already have a webcam that I never use and no proper application for motion capture (yet), let me know how everything goes!